# Suggestions for data recovery from an external hard-disk 

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, ubuntu-11.04

Recently when I was installing Ubuntu on my Laptop, I had an external 500 GB SeaGate hard-drive attached to the Laptop. During the installation setup Ubuntu asked where I would like to have my Operating system installed.

2 options were listed:

1. My 500 GB laptop hard drive.
2. My 500 GB Seagate external hard-drive.

By mistake I clicked on option 2 and proceeded to install. After 10 seconds I realised my mistake and hurriedly unplugged the Seagate device.

Now when I plug in this hard-disk into any computer, that computer is unable to detect it. No icon appears on the desktop in Ubuntu and I dont know how to access all the data 
stored on  the hard-disk.

However when I go to the boot manager of my BIOS, (which is used to decide which device to boot from) , 
I can see that device being detected as "Seagate Freeagent GO"

Please let me know how I should proceed and retrieve all the data from this device.

I currently have Ubuntu 11.04 installed on my laptop

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `testdisk` which might be able to recover the MBR/partitions on this device. If this does not work anymore try `photorec` which will attempt to pull of the data of the device by identifying file headers. This is 100% reliable but will also work if crucial parts of the file system were already overwritten.

And oh: Do not perform these tests on the hard disk but instead create an image of it via `dd` where you can safely experiment on. This way you do not risk to damage the data further in case you decide to hand over the HDD to a professional data recovery company later.

The `dd` command basically works as follows: `dd if=<INPUT> of=<OUTPUT> bs=1M` where
`INPUT` would be something like `/dev/sdX(n)` and `OUTPUT` would be a filename like `./diskimage.img`

Comment: Ahh thank you for the suggestion.....I will look into it. I did not know there were companies that dealt with data recovery. Thanks for the info...

Comment: can you tel me how to use the dd command in this specific case. online tutorials seem a little confusing on this point.

Comment: There are, but their services are expensive, so in most cases this is only an option if the data is really important. I've included basic instructions for `dd` in my original answer

Comment: @leepfrog Had this company recover 1.3tb data after a similar mistake, got 100% recovery for $199 + shipping one way....http://www.lowcostrecovery.com/pricing.html